# too many arguments in function call in c?

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, c-strings

I'm trying to create a menu of colors but the last line reported some error.

```
puts("I don't know about the color %c",input);
```

Here's the declaration

```
char input[7];
```

And the initialization

```
scanf("%c",&input);
```

The error is here

```
Too many arguments in function call
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
scanf("%c",&input);
        ^
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
scanf("%c",&input);
   ^~~~
```

Why is it?

Comment: The function `puts()` takes a single argument, a string, and does no formatting on the string other than adding a newline at the end.  The error message is about `scanf()`, though, which makes it odd that you're asking about (showing) a line containing `puts()`.  I think there's another problem on the line before the `scanf()` statement that you show.  The error messages don't make sense without that preceding (erroneous) context.

Comment: consider that `input` is a kind of pointer. if you want to set `input[0]`, please try this. `scanf("%c", input);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters this call

```
scanf("%c",&input);
      ^^^ ^^^
```

is incorrect. You have to write

```
scanf("%s", input);
      ^^^  ^^^
```

As for the error message then the function `puts` accepts only one argument. It seems you mean the function `printf` instead of `puts`. And the format specifier shall be `%s` instead of `%c` if you are going to output a whole string.

```
printf("I don't know about the color %s",input);
                                     ^^^
```

Otherwise if you was going to input only one character instead of a string then you need to write

```
scanf("%c",input);
```

and

```
printf("I don't know about the color %c\n",input[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding;

```
scanf("%c",&input);
```

A bare reference to an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  Therefore, the `&` is not needed (and will result in a compiler outputting a WARNing message.  This is what you are seeing

regarding:

```
puts("I don't know about the color %c",input);
```

the function: `puts()` can only take a single character string, no parameters.  One way to display the first character of `input[]` is:

```
printf( "%c\n", input[0] );
```